# SQL sub queries with WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to select all the characters that your character HAS NOT challenged in the past 24 hours.

```
 SELECT * FROM challenges
 WHERE userCharID = 642 AND chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

This returns a few rows with challenges that your character has initiated in the past day

```
SELECT characterID FROM CHARACTERS 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM challenges
                   WHERE userCharID = '610'
                     AND chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Am I using WHERE NOT EXISTS wrong?

Comment: Why is the comparison value for `userCharID` in quotes in one query and not in the other; and why is it 642 in one query and 610 in the other?  Does this matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I using WHERE NOT EXISTS wrong?

Yes.  You want to be using NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS.  If you use NOT EXISTS and the non-existential sub-query returns any rows, then the condition will be false and no data will be returned by the main query.  If no rows are returned, then the condition will be true and all rows will be returned by the main query (since, in this example, there are no other criteria in the main query).  Often, the sub-query in a NOT EXISTS is a correlated sub-query, so the sub-query has to be evaluated for each row.  Here, you don't have a correlated sub-query (which is good for performance).  But your query means 'return information about all characters unless there exists some character who's been challenged in the last one day by the nominated user'.

(*In this analysis, I've quietly changed the SQL so that `userCharID` is always compared with a string, and with the value `'642'` specifically.*)

> Select all the characters that your character [*has*] challenged in the past 24 hours:
>
> ```
> SELECT *
>   FROM Challenges
>  WHERE userCharID = '642'
>    AND chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
> ```
>
> This returns a few rows with challenges that your character has initiated in the past day.

So, to find all the people that you have not challenged, you need to select all the users except those in the list you have challenged, which translates to:

```
SELECT characterID
  FROM Characters 
 WHERE userCharID NOT IN
       (SELECT userCharID
          FROM Challenges
         WHERE userCharID = '642'
           AND chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
       )
```

This should give you the (possibly rather large) list of characters who you've not challenged within the last 24 hours.

Comment: Awesome answer, any way to optimize this? It seems NOT IN is a very expensive operation.

Comment: NOT IN can be an expensive operation.  You're using MySQL, and optimization for MySQL is outside my main area of expertise.  If it was an IN operation and that was being expensive, then you'd replace it with a JOIN.  However, the NOT IN is also `!= ALL` (that is, you could write `userCharID != ALL (SELECT ...)`, and that gives a hint about why it is expensive; it has to compare each of a very large number of characters with each of a relatively small list of challenged characters.  If the optimizer does not ensure that access to the 'NOT IN list' is appropriately optimized, it will crawl.

Comment: Note that if the list is small enough, linear search may be optimal.  If the list of challenged characters is bigger, then some sort of hash or indexed (binary tree or simply ordered array and binary search) search is probably appropriate.  But does the optimizer realize this.  Also, double check that it is not re-establishing the list each time it checks a character; that would be bad in this example.  (It would be normal if it was a correlated sub-query; this is not a correlated sub-query and it should not be treated as such.)

Comment: I'm assuming that `Challenges.userCharID` has an index on it?.. I also think that subqueries in general are expensive when they return many values because the optimizer usually does a full table scan on them!

Answer (score 2):

[WHERE NOT EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) in the context of a subquery returns TRUE or FALSE depending on the result.

> If a subquery returns any rows at all, EXISTS subquery is TRUE, and NOT EXISTS subquery is FALSE.

in your case it means that if

```
(SELECT * FROM challenges
WHERE userCharID = '610' AND chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

returns any rows at all then

your query wil be evaluated as

```
SELECT characterID FROM CHARACTERS WHERE FALSE;
```

which obviously is not what you want.

You can use the [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html) operator instead:

```
SELECT characterID FROM CHARACTERS 
WHERE characterID NOT IN (SELECT characterID FROM challenges
WHERE userCharID = '610' AND chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Where the second `characterID` (the one in the subquery) **needs to be the field that corresponds to the characterID in your CHARACTERS table**, this might be userCharID for you, though I doubt it, given your where clause. Without the schema I just can't tell for sure.

Other options at your disposal would be selecting directly [from the subquery](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) or in some cases getting your data through [joins](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried this on dev it worked well, however in production it slowed things to a crawl. Is there any way to optimize this query?

Comment: depends on your setup. Do you use any indexes? It's best to look into it with a query analyzer to see the type of internal query handling it does. We can't suggest you without having access to a database identical to you or at least table + index structures and the querypath used by your database. With mysql you get this info by preceding your sql statement with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html) even then database optimisation is a realm of its own, every server needs its specific settings.

Answer (score 0):

Your NOT EXIST query is really close. All you are missing is the correlation between the subquery and the outer query on characterID.

I've just added the alias `c` to the table on your outer query, an alias `d` to the table in your subquery, and added one predicate to the WHERE clause in your subquery

```
SELECT characterID FROM CHARACTERS c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM challenges d
                   WHERE d.userCharID = '610'
                     AND d.chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
                     AND d.characterID = c.characterID)
```

The "trick" here is the correlation matching `d.characterID` (from the table in the subquery) to `c.characterID` (from the table in the outer query.)

So, the query is checking for *each* character in that outer table, whether our user has had a challenge with *that* user in the last 24 hours. So, this query will return the result set you specified.

BUT... if you have a relatively large set of characters, and a relatively small set who have been challenged, this not likely going to be the fastest query that returns the result set.

---

Another approach to getting the result set is to use a LEFT JOIN with an IS NULL predicate (which we refer to as an "anti-join".) If this query:

```
SELECT d.characterID
  FROM challenges d
 WHERE d.userCharID = 642
   AND d.chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 GROUP BY d.characterID
```

returns a list of all characterID that have been challenged, which is the set of characters that you want to EXCLUDE from the set of ALL characters, then you can use that query as an inline view, like this:

```
SELECT n.characterID
  FROM characters n
  LEFT
  JOIN (
         SELECT d.characterID
           FROM challenges d
          WHERE d.userCharID = 642
            AND d.chalTime > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
          GROUP BY d.characterID
       ) c
    ON c.characterID = n.characterID
 WHERE c.characterID IS NULL
```

Here we are getting the list of all characters (n), and matching them to the list of characters that have been challenged (subquery aliases as c).  We use a `LEFT JOIN` operation because we want ALL rows from the characters table, whether a match is found or not.

The WHERE clause then throws out all the rows where we did find a match, so what we are left with is the set of characters who have not been challenged.

---

In my testing with large sets, this will usually outperforms a `NOT EXISTS` and a `NOT IN` (when appropriate indexes are available). But sometimes I find a `NOT IN` is faster, sometimes the `NOT EXISTS` is faster.

I find it's good to have all three approaches "in my pocket", and use whichever is most appropriate. I usually start with the anti-join pattern (it's what I'm used to writing), and then test both the `NOT EXISTS` and the `NOT IN` to compare performance.